# Makin new Object loses the variable Value

Tags: java

I have a log in system, the user logsin and a class called Model will store all information about that user (id, type, name)... etc

But when I make a new object of the Model class all the variable values get lost, meaning the value set previous by the class it self ain't initialised.

Everything is working fine expected when I call the new Model class,

```
public class TicketBlanks extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Model model;
/**
 * Creates new form TicketBlanks
 */
public TicketBlanks() {
    model = new Model();
    initComponents();
    fillAdvisorList();
}

public void fillAdvisorList() {
    DefaultListModel m = new DefaultListModel();
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ats?user=root&password=");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = 0 AND user_id !='" +model.getID() +"'";
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(SQL);

        System.out.print(model.getLoggedin());
        while(rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString("first_name") + " " + rs.getString("last_name");
                m.addElement(name);
        }
        SalesAdvisorsList.setModel(m);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

}
}
```

Comment: May we see your class `Model`? Especially it's constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly provide details of the class Model.
You can try making the variable of Class Model as static, this way they will retain the value.
e.g.

```
static int userID;
```

Comment: Thank you man, I totally forgot to use the static variables. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you store your values in `static` fields because if it's not the case this is normal.
Each `Object` have its own instance, so when you create a new one it is completely "empty".

In opposition static fields are linked to the class itself so they will be all the same from the different instantiation of your class that you have.